# How to create a dynamic dependent dropdown Select menu in jsp from the database using Jquery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

How can i select a faculty and it will only show me the departments in that faculty alone. My database name is getDbase and inside here i have three tables: 1. transfaculties table with two rows  (faculty_id and facultyname
2. transdepartments table with two rows (department_id and departmentname)
3. transfacdept table with three rows (transfacdept_id, faculty_id and department_id).This is the code I've written
This is my first jsp page code called Faculty.jsp

```
<%@page import="com.sua.db.DbManipulation"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.sua.db.DbConnection"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="forms.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {

                    jQuery('.faculty').change(function()
                    {
                            var idsss=$(this).val();
                            var dataString = 'fac_id='+ idsss;

                            jQuery.ajax
                            ({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "Department.jsp",
                                    data: dataString,
                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function(html)
                                    {
                                        jQuery('.dept').html(html); // result should be the class name of 'dept' dropdown (representing the Department)
                                    } 
                            });

                    });


            });

        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->  
    <div id="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="register">

                        <tr>
                        <td>Dropdown</td>
                            <td>
                            <select name="faculty" class="faculty" style="background-color: #ffffa0">
                                <option selected="selected">--Select Faculty--</option>
                                <%  //HttpSession session = request.getSession();

                                    String returnFacName = "SELECT `transfacdept`.`transfacdept_id`, `transfacdept`.`faculty_id`, "
                                        + "`transfacdept`.`department_id`, `transfaculties`.faculty_id, "
                                        + "`transfaculties`.facultyname "
                                        + "FROM `transfacdept`,`transfaculties` "
                                        + "WHERE `transfacdept`.`transfacdept_id` = `transfaculties`.faculty_id";
                                    Connection con = new DbConnection().getConnection();
                                    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(returnFacName);
                                    //ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                                    ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery(); 
                                    while(rs1.next())
                                    { 
                                        %>
                                            <option value="<%=rs1.getInt("faculty_id")%>">
                                                <%=rs1.getString("facultyname")%>
                                            </option>
                                        <%
                                    }
                                %>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                            <td>Dropdown 2:</td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="dept" class="dept" style="background-color: #ffffa0">
                                    <option selected="selected">--Select Dept--</option>

                                </select>
                            </td>
                            </tr>


            </div>


                                </div>
                                <br class="clear" />
                        </div>
                        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my second jsp page code called Department.jsp

```
<head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- ####################################################################################################### -->  
    <div id="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="register">


                        <td>Dropdown2</td>
                            <td>
                             <%     Connection con = new DbConnection().getConnection();
                                                    //Statement st = con.createStatement( );
                                    String $select = request.getParameter("fac_id");
                                                        String returnDeptName = "SELECT `transfacdept`.`transfacdept_id`, `transfacdept`.`faculty_id`, "
                                                                + "`transfacdept`.`department_id`, `transfaculties`.facultyname, "
                                                                + "`transdepartments`.departmentname "
                                                                + "FROM `transfacdept`, `transfaculties`, `transdepartments` "
                                                                + "WHERE `transfaculties`.faculty_id = '"+$select+"' "
                                                                + "AND `transfacdept`.`department_id` = `transdepartments`.department_id "
                                                                + "AND `transfacdept`.`faculty_id` = `transfaculties`.`faculty_id` ";

                                                        PreparedStatement st2 = con.prepareStatement(returnDeptName); 
                                                        ResultSet rs2=st2.executeQuery(); 
                                                        while(rs2.next())
                                                        { 
                                                            %>
                                                                <option value="<%=rs2.getInt("department_id")%>">
                                                                    <%=rs2.getString("departmentname")%>
                                                                </option>
                                                            <%
                                                        }
                                                    %>
                            </td>
                            </tr>



            </div>


                                </div>
                                <br class="clear" />
                        </div>
                        </div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->  

    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?
It only gives me the faculty without calling the department from the Jquery

Comment: ever heard of MVC?  Do not put java code into jsp, put in into servlets or other webservices and use JSTL in your JSP to display.  As you have probably discovered, how you have it is near to impossible to debug

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO.
Firstly as mentioned in comment the way you are doing it is totally wrong.

my advice is to go threw some AJAX-JAVA tutorials or even before that if you have not done how to use servlet first learn that and then goto AJAX.

here is a link that has detailed answer which you can go threw.
[stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Hope this helps.